# Is inner_join in R same as inner join in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, vertica

When I read tables from Vertica DB into R as dataframes and perform an inner_join I get different results compared to performing inner join on those two tables in Vertica on the same join conditions. Is there something that R does inner join differently than SQL join?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If the syntax is well formed, dplyr::inner_join does the same thing as a SQL inner join.  The difference is likely the "by =" vs "on". Can you share the code you are trying along with some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

In general, two different database engines should produce the same results for the same query on the same data.  There are some nuances to this.  Some things that come to mind:

First, the ordering of the result sets might be different, unless an `order by` is specified and the `order by` keys are unique.

Second, the default case-sensitivity might be different.  So, in one database strings might be compared distinguishing between upper and lower case.

The third consideration is an extension of the second:  the collations of the strings might be different and that can affect comparison results.

For numbers, you can have different internal representations -- for instance, 32-bit floats versus 64-bit floats.  However, using floating point numbers in joins is highly discouraged because they are "fuzzy" rather than precise values.

Datetime/timestamp comparisons could vary because of the precision of the seconds -- milliseconds versus nanoseconds, for instance.  Date comparisons should be the same, but default conversions from strings to dates might differ.

There are no doubt other subtleties.  The idea is that the code *should* be the same but there are environmental considerations on whether two values equal in one database are really equal  in the other.

Comment: Nice, seemingly-complete list of issues (meaning I can think of nothing more). Is it fair to lump timestamp comparisons in with floats? It's often the same argument, all based on IEEE-754 or related (unless the DMBS is using some other storage mechanism).